# Steam CS:GO on ubuntu playonlinux 10fps

Tags: steam, playonlinux

i am trying to play CS:GO via steam in ubuntu 18 Bionic Beaver machine but i get maximum 10 fps in game.

I have installed and deleted my graphics cards drivers about a hundred times but still no boost. I think game uses integrated CPU's Intel GPU instead of external NVIDIA GEFORCE but i am not sure.

All my in-game settings are configured to minimal.

Is it time to switch back to old reliable windows 10 or there is something more i can do?

Comment: Have you tried the Linux version of steam?

Comment: You need to learn that there are no switchable graphics on the fly in Linux.  With Intel+Nvidia use the Nvidia X Server Settings to select the profile (high performance for Nvidia) and reboot. Much more consistent and reliable. Also,  of course, always use a native version whenever available.

Comment: actually the Linux version of steam works much better, should have been my first choice, thank you guys! @GabrielaGarcia opening Nvidia X Server Settings results in a blank window of ubuntu software. Probably have messed too much with all this

Comment: That mean a problem with the Nvidia drivers.